# Как улучшить внешний вид WPF — программы?

Tags: wpf

Здравствуйте!

Пишу программу на WPF. Хотелось бы придать приложению красивый современный внешний вид. Особенно это касается DataGrid. Интересует что-нибудь в цветах Microsoft Office или похожее. Видел как оформлены контролы в DevExpress, нужно что-то подобное. Было бы очень хорошо, если бы тема меняла вид сразу всего приложения: и фона, и кнопок, и таблицы и т.д. И ещё. Где можно увидеть рекомендации или правила по тому, как должно быть оформлено приложение в целом: размеры кнопок, меню, статус-бара, выпадающих списков и прочего; возможно, рекомендации по расположению элементов в окне и их компоновки под какие-то типовые задачи (например: добавление нового сотрудника, форма ввода, организация меню и пр.).

Заранее спасибо.

P.S. Знаю про Telerik и DevExpress, но хотелось бы бесплатного решения.

Answer (score 3):

По поводу оформления, разумеется, в UX Style Guide.

Вот вам Microsoft Vista+ [User Experience Guidelines](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=2695) и Apple [Human Interface Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/OSXHIGuidelines/) (это для десктопных программ). Чтение длинное и скучноватое, и многое в стиле КО, но всё же большинство программ вокруг не делают и этого. Учтите, что когда вы это прочитаете, вы станете спецом по UI.

Заметьте, что стандартные контролы скорее всего удовлетворяют нужным гайдлайнам.

По поводу скинирования — не парьтесь. Если вы делаете коммерческий продукт, денег с первой же продажи хватит на покупку коммерческих библиотек. А если вы делаете бесплатный продукт — тем более не парьтесь, особенно в первой версии. Заскинировать можно всегда позже, WPF это позволяет.

Comment: Спасибо за толковый ответ. Но, если подскажете бесплатную тему или темы с поддержкой DataGrid, буду очень Вам благодарен.

Comment: @Сергио: Насчёт темы не подскажу, сорри, не в курсе.

Answer (score 3):

Попробуйте [ModernUI](https://github.com/firstfloorsoftware/mui).

[Cкриншоты](https://github.com/firstfloorsoftware/mui/wiki/Screenshots) выглядят довольно симпатично.

Совершенно бесплатно доступен через NuGet.

Можете еще попробовать http://datagridthemesfromsl.codeplex.com/.

И вот еще замечательные [темы в стиле MaterialDesing](https://github.com/ButchersBoy/MaterialDesignInXamlToolkit)

Answer (score 3):

Посмотрите [WPF Themes](http://wpf.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=WPF%20Themes) - бесплатная коллекция тем.

Answer (score 0):

Есть бесплатное решение, как в книжке [WPF: Windows Presentation Foundation в .NET 4.0 с примерами на C# 2010](http://www.twirpx.com/file/814794/), там примеров достаточно и к ним объяснение,и также есть ресурс на котором хранится достаточное количество примеров [код](http://professorweb.ru/my/WPF/themes/DarkBlue_UI/info_themes.php).

Answer (score 0):

Я использую только [mahapps](http://mahapps.com/). Бесплатно, информативно, куча тем и стилей. Все что нужно для хорошего приложения